# if (fn(val, key, this)) error (Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

This program should add role to a server member
Here is an error:

> Users\Администратор.ADMIN-5IU14HIGH\Desktop\DSBot\node_modules@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:235
> if (fn(val, key, this))
> ^ TypeError: fn is not a function

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const guild = new Discord.Guild();
module.exports = {
    name: 'role',
    description: 'role',
    execute(message, args) {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.some(791413811529515008);
        member.roles.add(role);
        
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`.some` takes in a function and returns `true` if some value in the collection matches the function. You pass in a value, so you get the error. You want to actually get the value at the key, so use the `get` function:

```js
let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(791413811529515008);
```